# Change styles of Material Bottom Tabs in React-Native

Tags: react-native

[image]

I want to change the following 
**indicator color (the oval when selected)**
**icon size**
**background color**
**any other possible changes in style**

Code for reference:

`import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs"`

`const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()`

`<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"> <Tab.Screen name="Home"/>`